# Kafka gives NoSuchElementException

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I created topic with multiple partition through Java code which is mention below.

```java
private void existOrCreateTopicsWithPartition(Properties prop) {
    String kafkaServer = prop.getProperty(KafkaProducerKey.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG.getKey());

    int replicationFactor = kafkaServer.split(BROKER_SEPERATION_REGEX).length;
    int totalPartionCount;
    ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(kafkaServer, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE,new SerializableSerializer());
    ZkUtils zkutils = new  ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(kafkaServer), false);
    String  producerTopics = prop.getProperty(KafkaProducerKey.PRODUCER_TOPICS.getKey());
    String topics[] = producerTopics.split(TOPICS_SEPERATOR_REGEX);
    for(String topic : topics){
        topic = topic.trim();

        if(!AdminUtils.topicExists(zkutils, topic)){
            totalPartionCount = Integer.valueOf(prop.getProperty(topic+PARTITION_KEY, "1"));
            AdminUtils.createTopic(zkutils, topic, totalPartionCount, replicationFactor, new Properties());
        }
    }


}
```

Once the java code run successfully I checked description of topic on kafka console use

```
org@org-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper  192.168.56.101:2181 --topic sms_cat_2 --describe
```

Which gives Error instead of result.

```
Error while executing topic command next on empty iterator  java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$3.next(Iterator.scala:27)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$3.next(Iterator.scala:25)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:90)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$.head(Map.scala:88)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$describeTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:147)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$describeTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:137)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.describeTopic(TopicCommand.scala:137)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:58)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

If I run consumer created with help of Spring-Integration it gives warning in infinite loop which looks like

```
WARN  NetworkClient:582 - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {sms_cat_1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE,  sms_cat_2=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
```

UPDATE : logs of below mention command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 192.168.56.101:2181 --describe

Topic:__consumer_offsets    PartitionCount:50    ReplicationFactor:1    Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=uncompressed
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 0    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 1    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 2    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 3    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 4    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 5    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 6    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 7    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 8    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 9    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 10    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 11    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 12    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 13    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 14    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 15    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 16    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 17    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 18    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 19    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 20    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 21    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 22    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 23    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 24    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 25    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 26    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 27    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 28    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 29    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 30    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 31    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 32    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 33    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 34    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 35    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 36    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 37    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 38    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 39    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 40    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 41    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 42    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 43    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 44    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 45    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 46    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 47    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 48    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 49    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0    Isr: 0  Error while executing topic command next on empty iterator  java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$3.next(Iterator.scala:27)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$3.next(Iterator.scala:25)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:90)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$.head(Map.scala:88)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$describeTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:147)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$describeTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:137)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.describeTopic(TopicCommand.scala:137)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:58)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Is there any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post result of following command `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper  192.168.56.101:2181 --describe` ?

Comment: find the updated question

Comment: It seems it is close to following Kafka Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1737

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and I described the topic on Kafka, founding that one of the partitions is `Leader: -1`.